# Unable to get simple PHP form to add/update to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a MySQL table with three columns; user, product, address. I am trying to get my form to either add to the table a NEW ROW OF DATA **OR** UPDATE a pre-existing row. My conditions for update are IF both user and product already exist, just change address. BUT IF neither exist (user and product), or just user, then append new user, product, and address info.

The form uses customer id, a dropdown box for the product, and a text box for the new address, however my SQL command for update seems to fail the page and I cannot find the error... Here is my attempt at MySQL code:

**EDITED TESTED CODE - Still not working**

```
mysqli_select_db("wp_newaddress", $con);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$id = $_POST['$userid'];
$product = $_POST['sku'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$sql = "UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='address' WHERE user='$userid' AND product='sku'";

echo "<p><h5>Change address:</h5>";

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<br><select name="sku">';
    echo '<option>-- Select product--</option>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  global $product;
    echo '<option value=' . $product->get_sku() . '>' . $product->get_sku() . ' </option>';
  endwhile;
echo '</select>';
echo '<br><input type="text" value="Insert new address here" id="address" size="40" />';
echo '<br><button type="submit" name="submit">Change address</button>';
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated address successfully\n";
```

Comment: You are using `mysql` as well as `mysqli`? Note that `mysql` is deprecated and you shoud use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: @btx I have edited my question - only using mysqli. I changed my code and still not working :(

Comment: Substituting string values into a query makes your code very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please read about them, then rewrite your code using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thats right, this is very dangerous code. E.g. if I put in as userid: `5'; DELETE FROM wp_newaddress;` it will drop your entire table. Always bind any parameters using [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). You might also get a lot more overview if you try to use the Object oriented style ;-)

Comment: @btx thank you for letting my know... Still novice at MySQL and trying to learn as I go!

Comment: You might also have a look at [PDO as alternative to mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). In many cases it is a lot easier in my opinion and more powerful.

Comment: Can you show the error from the error.log in the server?

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `mysqli_query`: `mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);`. See the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

You have to switch $sql and $con in `$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );`
In my opinion you also have to define $sql  as string.

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='address' WHERE user='$userid' AND product='sku'";
```

Comment: @Zoe Will the UPDATE sql command also work to add a new row if either userid or product is not already in the table? thanks!

Comment: @NicholasRavanelli I'm not the answerer, I just edited it. Btx wrote the answer, you should ping them instead. :)

Comment: Sorry! @btx  Will the UPDATE sql command also work to add a new row if either userid or product is not already in the table? thanks!

Comment: @btx I have updated my question with the code I am using but my page is still not working - that is it wont submit the query to the table (and my connection to the table is ok since I can see another table in the database on the same page).

Comment: You might missed the `$`at `"UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='address' WHERE user='$userid'`. But definitely see my comment above SQL injections. You should bind both variables on the query using [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='address' WHERE user='$userid' AND product='sku'");
```

This code executes the query.

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure

$sql contains the above possible return values.

Thus when you try to execute the query second time in the line

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );
```

It is not executing the sql statement rather the return value.

For example:
if the return of the first `mysqli_query()` is FALSE,
then your second `mysqli_query('FALSE', $con)`

so to correct it, you will need to do

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='$address' WHERE user='$userid' AND product='sku'";
```